# Change home directory

Tags: windows-10, bash, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to access a folder with a bunch of files via `cd $HOME_KADATH` however I'm thrown into my 'normal' home directory. Is there anyway to change the home directory to the one above instead?

This is how my environment variables are looking if it's to any help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are in Windows, and probably in WSL. You can't directly get windows environment variables in WSL. This should do the trick:

```
HOME_KADATH="$(cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%HOME_KADATH%" 2>/dev/null)"
```

Then

```
cd $HOME_KADATH
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean putting '"$(cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%HOME_KADATH%" 2>/dev/null)"' where I now have C:\Kadath in the systemvariabler instead?

Comment: No run it in Wsl

Comment: THanks but it didn't make a differnece. I'm returned with '-bash: nul: no such file or dorectory'.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has the ability to share environment variables with WSL.

This is specified via an environment variable (of course) named `WSLENV`.

To make HOME_KADATH available in WSL, create the environment variable `WSLENV`
with the value of `HOME_KADATH/p`.

Reference :
[Share Environment Vars between WSL and Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/).